# Inverse of Third Party Authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, aws, third-party

Consider this scenario. I have a file hosted on AWS with private access. I want the file to be accessible to several authorized users of a web applicaton that I have built. As I am the one authenticating these users, how do I tell AWS to delever the file only to users authenticated by my applicaton?

This seems somewhat like Oauth turned around where I am the third party authenticator between Amazon and the user. It seems like a common paradigm but I'm ignorant and can't think of what to even search for. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You need to get a signed URL from Amazon that allows access to the file for a limited time. This should be in the documentation. You can also send those files through your application if you prefer. This is more of a „how to use s3“ question, not a security question.

Comment: @averell Thanks, I'll look into signed URLs. The approach seems like a workaround though. If my user logs out, I don't have the ability revoke access to the resource. Plus the time period for which a resoruce is needed by the user might be unknown.

Comment: Is there any other similar technique being used by other service providers aprt from signed URLs?

Comment: The timeout for the resource is usually short, if the user needs to access it again they will get a new link. Of course can also pipe the data through your own app and use your own access control.